# Reading array of objects from a .dat file java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an array of objects in a saved file.dat and i want to restore them into an array of the same object to my java program to use them into my program
 this is my code but doesn't work at all

```
    public static void  main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {

Seat[] arr = new Seat [100];

try{
    File f = new File("reservedSeats.dat");
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(fs); 
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    temp=ds.readInt();
     arr[i] = new Seat (String.valueOf(temp)/*to convert from int to String*/);
   }

 }
catch ( FileNotFoundException e ){

}

for (Seat arr1 : arr) {
    System.out.println(arr1);
}
```

My Seat.java constructor as follows :

```
    public Seat(String seatNo)
{
    this.seatNo = seatNo;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work at all" How? Any errors?

Comment: What is the format of the file?  You are reading it as binary?  Are you sure it is not text?

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria it gives me nulls when i print the arr

Comment: Can you show us the code for how it was written?  Without his there is no way to know how it should be read.

Comment: @PeterLawrey my file is .dat it has an array of seats

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am not the one who wrote it

Comment: Most likely your Seat.toString() is broken as there is no way the code provided will have a `null` printed.

Comment: @user3585537 Then ask the person who write it what the format is, or read the code they wrote.

Comment: Are you certain it's finding the file and loading _anything_?  The `FileNotFoundException` handler silently ignores a missing file, so `arr` would just be 100 null values.

Comment: @stridecolossus Good point, if the file doesn't exist, or is not in the expected directory it will be null.  This is a good reason to a) don't pretend exceptions don't matter as if they didn't happen. b) printout your exception unless you know they don't matter.

Comment: @stridecolossus that's right , the exception FileNotFoundException appears  , i'll try to solve it and come back

Comment: You should post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ObjectInputStream:

```
ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("reservedSeats.dat"));
Seat[] lst = (Seat[]) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: I dont think there are exactly 100 seats and i think the number is inside Seat.